# Is strtok in C89?

Tags: c, strtok

Is the strtok function in standard C89?

Comment: You could ask such a question here for every single function used in any C program, or you could look it up.

Comment: Where can you check if a function belongs to a given standard in an easy way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the man page says:

```
CONFORMING TO
       strtok()
              SVr4, POSIX.1-2001, 4.3BSD, C89, C99.

       strtok_r()
              POSIX.1-2001.
```

So I would say yes.

According to the C89 draft I have (the actual standard costs money), the appropriate section is:

> **4.11 STRING HANDLING <string.h>**
>
> **4.11.5.8 The strtok function**

Answer (score 1):

There are lists enumerating functions and other identifiers by standard and header.
See e.g. http://www.schweikhardt.net/identifiers.html